# Replace ANSI color code from string in vimscript

Tags: vim

I have a string variable in vimscript that contains some ANSI escape characters used for highlighting purposes. The string looks like,

```
^[[32m MyStringBody ^[[0m
```

I've put the escape code literally as vim displays it, it is the escape sequence - Ctrl-v-[.

I want to replace all occurences of such escape characters with a `substitute` command.

```
substitute(my_variable, pattern, '', 'g')
```

Can someone help me with a regex pattern that would remove these escape characters. Thanks.

Comment: your vim display `^[[0m` as literal text or as key sequence?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The special atom `\e` matches the `<Esc>` = `^[`:

```
substitute(my_variable, '\e\[[0-9;]\+[mK]', '', 'g')
```

You could also use `\%d27` (`<Esc>` is decimal 27) or `\%x1b` (hexadecimal). The pattern should match (most) ANSI escape sequences.

Comment: Learn one thing a day and keep the boredom away. Thanks Ingo (and Vim).

Answer (score 3):

Just use `<C-v><Esc>` to input the `^[` character in the following command:

```
substitute(my_variable, '^[[\d+m', '', 'g')
```