# How to nicely display console colors in PM2 logs file?

Tags: logging, vim, server, terminal, pm2

I have a pm2 node.js process running. Everything is good, console logs and errors display very well in the terminal.

But as soon as I open logs file with vim or nano rather than view them with `pm2 logs`, I get a mess !

It looks like that :

```
01/07/2021 09:10:19 GMT+00:00: ^[[0mPOST /auth/refresh ^[[33m404^[[0m 4.601 ms - 74^[[0m
01/07/2021 09:10:20 GMT+00:00: ^[[0mPOST /auth/refresh ^[[33m404^[[0m 0.868 ms - 
01/07/2021 09:10:28 GMT+00:00: ^[[0mPOST /auth/ ^[[32m200^[[0m 163.059 ms - 677^[[0m
01/07/2021 09:10:28 GMT+00:00: ^[[0mGET /messages/info/by-role/3 ^[[32m200^[[0m 8.993 ms - 586^[[0m
01/07/2021 09:10:28 GMT+00:00: ^[[0mGET /exchanges/lasts/9?limit=5 ^[[32m200^[[0m 10.884 ms - 484^[[0m
```

I do think it's because of colors. They are only well interpreted by the terminal but are weirdly stored. One of the solution could be to remove those colors but I was wondering if there is a way to just display them nicely in vim, nano or another text editor.

Comment: There is nothing weird, those are [ANSI color codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) embedded in the file. `vim` cannot display them as colors. Try `less -R`

Comment: It work perfectly ! Thanks ! Can you add an answer so that I can accept it as the solution ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing weird, those escape codes are [ANSI color codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#Colors) embedded in the file.

`vim` cannot display them as colors and I don't know any plugin to convert them to vim colors. Either [remove them](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18102999/7976758) or use a different program.

Try [`less -R`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/less).